# Assemble string concat in template

Tags: javascript, assemble

I want to concat two strings inside a template, for example:

```
{{>
 masthead
 title=car-and.panel1.title
 image=  (imageBase "myimage.jpg")
 height="100"
}}
```

So I want to register a concat helper with assemble.  None of the ways I've found in the docs seem to work though.
I have a helper:

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper("imageBase", (path) => "/images/" + path);
};
```

I am initialising the app with these options:

```
const app = assemble({
  ext: "html",
  helpers: ['./app/helpers/*.js' ]
});
```

I always get the error that it can't find the helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were looking at some of the `grunt-assemble` documentation and trying to apply that to the latest version of `assemble`. We're still working on getting all of that updated, but the [assemble README](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) is a good place to start for new documentation.

Also, for the helpers specifically, that api is provided by `templates` and is documented here: https://github.com/jonschlinkert/templates#helper

So to update your code example, you can do this to register the helper:

```
const app = assemble();
app.helper('imageBase', (path) => '/images/' + path);
```